# Differentiate between multiple Google APIs calling onConnected

Tags: android, google-api, google-api-client

So I have an app that uses both the google+ api to allow users to sign in, as well as the cast api to allow users to cast content to a chromecast.

However, both APIs use the same connection callbacks.

What is the best practice for differentiating between which API should be notified of the connection callback?

For example, onConnected() is called when the user succesfully signs in. But it is also called when the connection to the chromecast has been established. How do I differentiate between the two scenarios?

Edit: So I found this info from Google:

> Note that the contents of the connectionHint Bundle are defined by the specific services. Please see the documentation of the specific implementation of GoogleApiClient you are using for more information.

However, I cannot find the documentation that describes the connectionHint contents for different APIs.

Edit2: Could I just create a separate API client for each API?

Comment: The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client) recommends connecting a client in the onStart() method of the using activity and disconnecting in onStop().  Is your google+ processing and chromecast processing in different activities?  If so, it seems like to follow the recommendation for connection lifecycle managment, you might want to have a GoogleApiClients for each activity, resulting in separate callbacks for each one.  In other words, each activity would have its own onConnected().

Comment: As a side note, I just confirmed by looking at log output that when a GoogleApiClient is connected for Google Drive, the bundle returned in onConnected() is null; there are no connection hints. Like you, I searched and couldn't find them documented anywhere.  Maybe for future enhancement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach is to use multiple clients, one for each API and then attach separate callbacks to them to be able to distinguish them.

Comment: This is the method I decided to use.